# ubuntu 18 - mouse right click

Tags: ubuntu

I installed the brand new Ubuntu 18.04 when I suddenly realize that right click on my touchpad doesn’t work. I've tried to seethe common settings (mouse and touchpad) but it does not have an option to be configured

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. I suggest deleting it and reposting in [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature of this version, but you can find the solution at https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/ . Basically you have to install tweaks to fix it.